# HttpPost variables and PHP error

Tags: php, android, httpresponse, http-get

.PHP file successfully works by creating a db connection and inserting sql.
My only conclusion then it is somewhere in the .java activity 
..and yes I have set INTERNET PERMISSIONS within manifest.

MY ERROR: 01-03 21:56:05.784: W/System.err(1398): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //setContentView(R.layout.email);
            try {
                postInternetData();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

private void postInternetData() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/app/insert_tag.php");

    try{            
        List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "android"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity (formparams));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }   

    }

<?php
// CREATE the connection
$connection = mysql_connect('XXXXXXXXXXX.db.godaddy.com','XXXXXXXXXXX','XXXXXXXXXXX');
if(!$connection) {
    echo 'failure to connect host';
}

$mysql_select_db = mysql_select_db('XXXXXXXXXXX', $connection);

if(!$mysql_select_db) {
    echo 'failure to select db';
}

$name = $_POST['name'];

$qry = "INSERT INTO httptest(id, name) VALUES ('', '" . $name . "');";

$result = mysql_query($qry, $connection);
IF (!$result){
    echo 'failure to query db';
} else {
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

After hours of troubleshooting through stackoverflow examples and man files, I fold.
Is there anything that stands out to you?
Thanks.

Comment: What does "unable to interact with the posted variables" mean? What are we looking at here? Where's the PHP script?

Comment: I will post the php contents.

Comment: @Peceiver Please post the PHP by editing your original post, rather than in a comment.

Comment: the php file successfully generates connection and inserts sql statement; just inserts a blank where $name should be.

Comment: What is the value of response when you debug? Whats the response code, etc... ?

Comment: I am very new to android dev and cannot seem to generate any logcat file with this operation.

Comment: ahh.. I am getting a 'network on main thread err'

Comment: Add e.printstacktrace(); in both catch blocks, you will see logcat. Recently I was able to implement similar functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Android 3.0 if you have any network operations (eg. connecting to your site) on the main (aka GUI) thread, the application throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Try testing in an emulator running 2.2 to see if it works (and there are no other bugs in your code). Otherwise to make it work on 3.x and 4.x, you'll need to take a look at [threading](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) in Android. A tutorial can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

Answer (score 2):

Like others have mentioned, Android no longer allows any network activity on the UI thread. Even if they did, you must not do so, because for the duration of the network activity, the UI will be unresponsive which contributes to a poor User Experience.

What you need to use is [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

This is how you would call an `ASyncTask`

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

And this is how you set it up

```
private final class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>   
    {
        private ProgressDialog progressdialog;
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("http://example.com/getinfo"));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                {               
                    //successful response                   
                }
                else
                {
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                ProgressDialog.show(HelloWorldActivity.this,"","Failed",true);              
            }           
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            if (progressdialog.isShowing())
                progressdialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(HelloWorldActivity.this,"Completed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
        }       

        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressdialog = ProgressDialog.show(HelloWorldActivity.this,"","Working...",true);
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely, StrictMode is enabled on the UI thread.

Try:

```js
ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
```

The above is not recommended practice though, I think you need to use an [AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html).